# NextJS: Error serializing `.data.data` returned from `getServerSideProps`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, next.js

I'm new to NextJS. I'm working on a simple page in which I need to retrieve data from my backend app. My backend app is a totally separate app written in go. My undestanding is that I must use `getServerSideProps` to get data from the server on load, so I've got the following:

`myProject/pages/category/new.js`:

```
export default function AddNewCategory(data) {
...
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
    const data = await getAllCategories();
    console.log(await data)
    return {
        props: {
            data: { data }
        }
    };
};
```

`myProject/api/category.js`:

```
import axios from "axios";

// getAllCategories returns a list of all active categories
export const getAllCategories = async() => {

    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/categories")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("error")
            console.log(error)
        })

}
```

As you can see I've got a print statement in `getAllCategories` which prints:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Pop',
      slug: 'pop',
      description: 'Pop',
      parent: 0,
      active: true,
      created_at: '2022-05-03T19:50:00-04:00',
      updated_at: '2022-05-03T19:50:00-04:00',
      deleted_at: null
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Pop 2',
      slug: 'pop-2',
      description: 'Pop',
      parent: 0,
      active: true,
      created_at: '2022-05-03T19:50:24-04:00',
      updated_at: '2022-05-03T19:50:24-04:00',
      deleted_at: null
    }
  ]
}
```

yet I'm getting the following error:

> error - Error: Error serializing `.data.data` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/category/new".
> Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.

I saw around that I should try to convert the data to string and then back to json:

```
return { 
  props: { 
    data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) 
  } 
};
```

but when I do this I'm getting a different error:

> error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I'm using `next@12.1.5`

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: While you're correct in saying the `console.log(response.data)` is logging the right thing, that's not what `await getAllCategories()` actually returns. That's because you're missing a return statement right before the `axios` call, i.e. `return axios.get(...).then(...).catch(...)`. Otherwise that function simply returns `undefined`.

Comment: you're correct @juliomalves, that solved my issue. Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer so it can be more visible to other people. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to convert your json to a javascript object with [.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json). The following code comes from [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#using-getserversideprops-to-fetch-data-at-request-time).

```js
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await getAllCategories();
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}
```

**EDIT**

In this particular case it was not necessary to add `const data = await res.json()` because the request is made via axios, and in axios responses are already served as javascript object, so there's no need to parse.

Comment: Hi. I did what you suggested but am getting now: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'json')`

Comment: Right, because as mentioned @juliomalves you should add `return` right before the axios call in  your `getAllCategories` function, otherwise the function doesn't return anything (that's probably why you're getting an `undefined` error).

Comment: yes, you guys are right, that was the issue. Thanks a lot